# Give correct Sql Query

Tags: sql, oracle10g, db2

I have two queries,

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3
  from scnd1
 where col2<>'' 
 group by col1,col2,col3 
 order by col1

SELECT ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1) AS RN FROM SCND1)AS A
 WHERE RN > 1
```

For same table, I need single query to combine these two
 ie. 1st I want to sort table as well as remove `NULL` and then delete the repeated rows by 2nd query.

Comment: The second statement is invalid syntax for every DBMS out there.

Answer (score 0):

Try a sub query, along the lines of this:

```
SELECT 
    main.col1, 
    main.col2,
    main.col3 
FROM scnd1 main
JOIN (SELECT 
         col1,
         col2,
         col3, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY(col1) ORDER BY col1) AS RN
      FROM SCND1
      WHERE col2<>''
) sub
ON sub.Col1 = main.Col1 AND sub.Col2 = main.col2 AND sub.Col3 = main.col3
WHERE RN > 1
GROUP BY main.col1,main.col2,main.col3 
ORDER BY main.col1
```

Comment: ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1) AS RN  -- this is not correct

Comment: Thanks, hadn't noticed.  Corrected this now

Comment: That is the SQL server syntax... is ORACLE different for ROW_NUMBER()?

Comment: thanks paul & anand..  i tried this query, but i shows (column ambiguously defined (SQL-HY000)) this error for me..

Comment: It's ambiguous because of `WHERE col2 <> ''`, which needs a table alias.  However, I'm fairly certain that checking for null should be _inside_ the 'subquery', as the OP seems to want the first row that _doesn't_ have nulls...